# Schedule something for a specific time in Java?

Tags: java, date, timer, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a scheduled task at a specific time every day.

I have this so far:

```
Date timeToRun = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Timer myTimer = new Timer();

myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        //Method to run
    }
}, timeToRun);
```

How would I set `timeToRun` to a specific time? So that I can run this code on any particular date, and it would run the task at the correct time; e.g. 7:30pm every day.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a date object with specific time, here is the code -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);

Date timeoRun = cal.getTime();
```

Editing to accommodate the requirement as posted in the comment -

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis()>timeToRun.getTime()){
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
}
timeToRun = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(timeToRun);
```

In the above code, checking if the current time is greater than the computed time, if so, increment the date.

Comment: I have updated the code to accommodate your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;

public final class FetchMail extends TimerTask {

/** Construct and use a TimerTask and Timer. */
public static void main (String... arguments ) {
TimerTask fetchMail = new FetchMail();
//perform the task once a day at 4 a.m., starting tomorrow morning
//(other styles are possible as well)
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(fetchMail, getTomorrowMorning4am(), fONCE_PER_DAY);
}

/**
* Implements TimerTask's abstract run method.
*/
@Override public void run(){
//toy implementation
System.out.println("Fetching mail...");
}

// PRIVATE

//expressed in milliseconds
private final static long fONCE_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24;

private final static int fONE_DAY = 1;
private final static int fFOUR_AM = 4;
private final static int fZERO_MINUTES = 0;

private static Date getTomorrowMorning4am(){
Calendar tomorrow = new GregorianCalendar();
tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, fONE_DAY);
Calendar result = new GregorianCalendar(
tomorrow.get(Calendar.YEAR),
tomorrow.get(Calendar.MONTH),
tomorrow.get(Calendar.DATE),
fFOUR_AM,
fZERO_MINUTES
);
return result.getTime();

}


}
```

Here, a task is performed once a day at 4 a.m., starting tomorrow morning using Timer and TimerTask.

Answer (score 0):

It's onliny an argument more

```
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        //Method to run
    }
}, timeToRun, 24*60*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

## ScheduledExecutorService

The [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) interface was added to Java 5 to serve your purpose.

An alternative to Timer. Both have pros and cons you should study before choosing.

In particular beware that…

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.

As described in [this humorous post](http://code.nomad-labs.com/2011/12/09/mother-fk-the-scheduledexecutorservice/), the service silently quits running any more executions if any exception is thrown. One workaround I use is to wrap the entire code being run with general try-catch (and log) for the most generic Exception.